# Перестал работать Django Channels

Tags: python, django

Ранее на компе разрабатывал проект на `django channels`. Сейчас нужно продолжить на ноуте, поставил сюда `Python`, `Django`, чаннелсы, попробовал запустить проект - и он запускается как обычный `wsgi`. Не выходит на подобие `starting ASGI server`. Подумал мб чёт намудрил и решил открыть бэкап этого же проекта что ранее точно запускался - результат один и тот же. Попробовал скинуть версии `Python`, `Django` с последних на чуть меньше, тоже никакой разницы. Help?

p.s. Он запускается с `daphne`, но с `python manage.py runserver` - нет

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Изменить версию channels.

```
pip uninstall channels

pip install channels==3.0.4
```

Comment: По идее можно одной строкой `pip install -U channels==3.0.4`